# Was Liz Toomes drawing at the beginning of Spider-Man: Homecoming showing us something important?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

I have downloaded a high-quality picture of that drawing from Pinterest. It's not the original one, but it's completely the same.

Liz Toomes had sketched the battle of New York on a paper.

The drawing important features:

- Captain America's black star; which was on his suit in *Avengers: Infinity War*.
- Iron Man's pentagon-shaped arc reactor; which was present on his suit in *Captain America: Civil War*.
- Hawkeye's sword; which he was yielding in *Avengers: Endgame*.
- The Hulk's red eyes; which he got them in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Were these just intentionally implemented into the movie for making references to other Marvel movies, or it was an important thing?

[image]

Comment: Or they could be nothing.  A kids drawing, done after the events, with more recent photos of the heroes.  Hawkeye obviously had a bow at the battle, and that might just be a poor rendition of a curved bow.

Comment: A lot of movie franchises like to throw in Easter eggs like this, simply for the fun of it. For example, [check out #34](https://screenrant.com/spider-man-movie-easter-eggs-homecoming-marvel/)

Comment: [What culture](https://whatculture.com/film/10-insane-mcu-details-nobody-noticed?page=8) got the real drawing I guess which is almost the same

Comment: [Related question on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/242304/76048) regarding Barton specifically.

Comment: @iandotkelly She drew it in the same year the battle of New York occurred.